# How to remove g++ 4.1.2 totally

Tags: path, g++

I used to install g++ 4.1.2 (from source make install)on my ubuntu 10.04.
Then I find it cover the the original 4.3.3. and change the search path of g++ from /usr/bin to /usr/local/bin,
How can I remove g++4.1.2 totally? I tried make remove.However it do not work.

Btw, how to change g++ path to /usr/bin?

Answer (score 1):

`make uninstall` is not included/supported in GCC, so you're out of luck. The one thing you can do (leaving a bunch of non-pacakage-manager-tracked files in your filesystem) is reinstall the GCC 4.3.3 package, overwriting existing (4.2.1) files.